# Filtrar datos de un arreglo en angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo el siguiente arreglo de objetos:

```
$scope.name = {
  "cliente":[
    {"id":1, "dato":"des"},{"id":2, "dato":"eeeee"}
   ],
  "detalle":[{"id":1, "dato":"oooo"},{"id":2, "dato":"ccccc"},{"id":2, "dato":"xxxxxxxxx"},{"id":2, "dato":"zzzzzzz"}]

}
```

el cual es recorrido para asignar a un nuevo arreglo todos los datos que correspondan al id del objeto cliente. Este es mi controller

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.arreglo = [];
    $scope.name = {
  "cliente":[
    {"id":1, "dato":"des"},{"id":2, "dato":"eeeee"}
   ],
  "detalle":[{"id":1, "dato":"oooo"},{"id":2, "dato":"ccccc"},{"id":2, "dato":"xxxxxxxxx"},{"id":2, "dato":"zzzzzzz"}]

}
for(var i=0; i<$scope.name.cliente.length;i++){
  for(var j=0; j<$scope.name.detalle.length;j++){
    if($scope.name.cliente[i].id == $scope.name.detalle[j].id){
      $scope.arreglo.push({"cliente":$scope.name.cliente[i].id, "detalle":$scope.name.detalle[j]})
    }
  }
}
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.arreglo))
}
```

Al imprimir $scope.arreglo el resultado es de la siguiente manera:

```
[{"cliente":1,"detalle":{"id":1,"dato":"oooo"}},{"cliente":2,"detalle":{"id":2,"dato":"ccccc"}},{"cliente":2,"detalle":{"id":2,"dato":"xxxxxxxxx"}},{"cliente":2,"detalle":{"id":2,"dato":"zzzzzzz"}}]
```

y lo que quiero es que se presente de esta forma:

```
[{"cliente":1,"detalle":{"id":1,"dato":"oooo"}},
{"cliente":2,"detalle":{"id":2,"dato":"ccccc", "dato":"xxxxxxxxx","dato":"zzzzzzz"}}]
```

En si lo que deseo es que se presente una sola vez el id del cliente junto con sus datos asociados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var names = {"cliente":[
    {"id":1, "dato":"des"},{"id":2, "dato":"eeeee"}
   ],
    "detalle": [{id:1, "dato":"oooo"},{id:2, "dato":"ccccc"},{id:2, "dato":"xxxxxxxxx"},{id:2, "dato":"zzzzzzz"}]
 }


var result= names.detalle.reduce((acc, item) => {
  let { id, dato } = item;
  id="cliente "+id;
  acc[id] = acc[id] || [];
  dato="dato "+dato;
  acc[id].push(dato);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Si, pienso que es mas o menos lo que quieres, creo que no es necesario colocar el id-cliente, en el detalle pues ya está viviendo en el cliente para el objeto de output. También deberías tener clara la diferencia entre definir el detalle como un arreglo [] o como atributos en un objeto {}, cuando dijiste "deseo que quede así", sería como si fuera un objeto dinámico, podría ser, pero parece que la estructura regular se dió más natural en este caso, a menos que estes seguro de porqué prefieres que sea un objeto con N atributos y tengas el motivo para preferirlo así antes que un arreglo

```
for(var i=0; i<$scope.name.cliente.length;i++){
  var cliente = {"cliente":$scope.name.cliente[i].id,"detalle":[]};
  for(var j=0; j<$scope.name.detalle.length;j++){
    if($scope.name.cliente[i].id == $scope.name.detalle[j].id){
       cliente.detalle.push($scope.name.detalle[j]);
    }
  }
  $scope.arreglo.push(cliente);
}
```